# Extract difference between two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two strings:

s1 = "hello how are you, this is a test"

s2 = "this is a test, testing testing."

Then, how can I extract the string of s2 which is not in s1 ?

```
diff = function(s1,s2) 
print(diff)
```

> ", testing testing."

Comment: If `s2` was not a substring of `s1`, what would you expect the function to return?

Comment: .. and are the positions relevant? What about `how are you, hello?` and `hello hello hello`? And what happened to ` ?` in your example?

Comment: Output would be `how are you?`

Comment: @MatsLindh True, thanks !

Comment: @khelwood Just an empty string ""

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, I rephrased my question. It was not clear enough. Please have a look. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MatsLindh Sorry, I rephrased my question. It was not clear enough. Please have a look. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```py
s1 = "hello how are you ?"

s2 = "hello"
if s2 in s1:
    print(s1.replace(s2, ''))
elif s1 in s2:
    print(s2.replace(s1, ''))
else:
    print('Not a substring')
```

> > Update

Use this then:

```py
s1 = "hello how are you, this is a test"

s2 = "this is a test, testing testing."

diff = ''
for word in s2.split():
    if word not in s1.split():
        diff += word + ' '
print(diff)
```

Comment: Sorry, I rephrased my question. It was not clear enough. Please have a look. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The best is levenshtein algorithm, you may calculate the distance between 2 sentences (how many character replacements it takes to convert one into another) or similarity ratio, if you like:

```
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> Levenshtein.distance( 'hello, guys', 'hello, girls' )
3
>>> Levenshtein.ratio( 'hello, guys', 'hello, girls' )
0.782608695652174
```

You may check the details of the implementation and other info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Sorry, I rephrased my question. It was not clear enough. Please have a look. Thank you very much.